# Update MongoDB with value from DF

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a dataframe example as follows:

```
   request            new_request
0  Whats the time     What's the time?
1  its late           it's late!
```

I then have a mongodb collection as follows:

```
{
    '_id': 'b5445',
    'request': 'Whats the time',
    'accepted': True,
    'aId': '6954c4',
    'createDate': '1610726929114'
}
{
    '_id': '4534fg', ,
    'request': 'its late',
    'accepted': True,
    'aId': 'a86dfsb',
    'createDate': '1610964941537'
}
```

I want to update the mongoDB collection so that it looks like:

```
{
    '_id': 'b5445',
    'request': "What's the time?",
    'accepted': True,
    'aId': '6954c4',
    'createDate': '1610726929114'
}
{
    '_id': '4534fg', 
    'request': "it's late!",
    'accepted': True,
    'aId': 'a86dfsb',
    'createDate': '1610964941537'
}
```

I am new to mongoDB so completely stuck. How do i do that?

Comment: I just formatted the data for easier reading, and I noticed there's an additional comma in the second block of data, after the `_id` field, should it be there?

Comment: You also have repeated fields in the last data block. I didn't remove them in case it was part of your question

Comment: Nope it shouldn't be like that. I've amended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
mydb = myclient['mydatabase']
mycol = mydb['customers']

#pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['request', 'new_request'], 
                  data = {'request': ['Whats the time', '''its late'''],
                          'new_request': ['''What's the time?''', '''it's late!''']}) 

#Update MongoDB collection one by one
for i in range(len(df)):
    myquery = { 'request': df.iloc[i]['request'] } 
    newvalues = { '$set': { 'request': df.iloc[i]['new_request'] } }
    
    mycol.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
```

More details here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_update.asp